# Making a header not change size when a page is scaled by a phone

Tags: javascript, css

So, there is an app that links to two different webpages.
The first one is made by me, it is responsive so when it is loaded on a phone everything fits nicely.

The other one is made by the company i work for and is not responsive.

Now I am supposed to add a bar at the top of both pages and when they are loaded in the app the bar needs to have the same size for both pages. I can not change anything on the non-responsive page, only the bar at the top.

Lets take 900px and 360px as an example, one page scales down to fit on 360px for the iphone and the other stays on 900px width so it is scaled down to fit on a mobile screen by the phone.

[http://imgur.com/6tV1IDT](https://imgur.com/6tV1IDT)

I need to make a bar for the 900px width one that always have the same height as the one on the 360px width page even if it is scaled down by different phones. (scaling down to differnt widths/heights)

Is there any way to set the height of an element to be ignored by phone scaling even if the rest of the page is scaled?

Comment: "Same size" in what sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was not worded so it was easy to understand but maybe someone will search something similar and end up here anyway so here is the way i solved it.

```
//get the width of the browser without the scaling 
//if the window is smaller than 260 my paged stopped scaling and started to use a horizontal scrollbar instead
//the minimum depends on your webpage I think. (Change the 260 to the minimum width of your page.
currentWidth = screen.width > 260 ? screen.width : 260;

//get the relative size depending on the size of the non-scaling webpage.
//The page I worked with had a width of 1050.
//If the browser is wider than the page set the size to 1.
relativeSize = screen.width < 1050 ? (1050/currentWidth) : 1;
```

After you got that value you can use relativeSize * (the size you have when it is not scaled) and it will end up being the same size even if the page is sized down.

I set it to the onLoad and onResize events and resized my header whenever the page size got changed. i.e. when someone flips a phone over you might want to resize again.

EDIT: screen.width instead of window.outerWidth to get it working on iphone.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just define `width: 100%;` for that bar it should work, also on the non-responsive page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the head of your document `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. As your question is horribly written it's hard to even understand what you want or trying to fix.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The rest of the head below... -->
</head>
```

Comment: Yeah I am sorry about how I worded it, was a bit stressed and a lot of things I am not allowed to mention. Gonna edit the question after I figure out a better way to say it.

Comment: Sorry, but with "a lot of things you're not allowed to mention", this is probably not going very far. If secrecy is more important than a proper problem description, then tell your company to take it to a contractor who'll sign an NDA. Otherwise, give proper examples of what the page's code looks like, and what exactly you want the end result to look like.